# phonegap/msql(i) can't establish connection to database

Tags: mysql, ios, phpmyadmin, cordova, database-connection

i'm currently developing an web app for iOS but the app can't get the connection right.

when i'm trying to log in, i get the following iOS popup: index.html Error.

while the PHP files are online,

here some of my code:

connection.php

```
<?php //Make connection with database
// Verbinden met MySQL Database
$host = "localhost"; // Welke server : localhost 
$username = "*******"; // Gebruikersnaam
$password = "****"; // Wachtwoord
$dbnaam = "*****"; // Naam van de database
$db_error1 = "<p>FOUT: verbinden met databaseserver is mislukt</p>"; // Foutmelding 1
$db_error2 = "<p>FOUT: selecteren van database is mislukt</p>"; // Foutmelding 2
$db_error3 = "<p>FOUT: sluiten van database is mislukt</p>"; // Foutmelding 3

// Verbinden met Databaseserver
$con=mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbnaam);// or die($db_error1);
// verbinden met de database
//mysql_select_db($dbnaam, $db) or die($db_error2);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

demo.js

```
// define the URL of the server component
//var url ="http://www.jorisgraaumans.nl/dutchmobile/";
//var url = "http://localhost:8888/Mobile/Festival/";
var url = "http://www.rikvandoorn.com/mobile/";

// afvangen van het standaard submit event
// zie ook: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

$('#login').on('pageinit', function(event) {
    $('#loginForm').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "processLogin.php",
            cache: "false",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                email : $('#email').val(),
                wachtwoord : $('#wachtwoord').val(),
            },
            success: function(phpData){ 
                $("#return").data("login", phpData.login);
                console.log("login is: "+ phpData.login);
                if(phpData['error'] == true){
                    $.mobile.changePage("#return", {
                        transition : "fade"
                    })
                } else {
                    $.mobile.changePage("#home", {
                        transition : "fade"
                    })
                }
            },  
            error: function(){
                    alert('Error');
            }                   
        }); 
        return false; // return false to prevent the default submit of the form to the server.
    });
    // end: pageinit loginForm  
});
$('#return').on('pageshow', function(event) {
    $("#error_message_log").empty();
    $("#error_message_log").prepend('<p>' +  $(this).data('login') + '</p>');
});
```

processLogin.php

```
<?php //process login form 

include 'http://www.rikvandoorn.nl/mobile/connect.php'; //connection to database
if(empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['wachtwoord'])){
    $return['error'] = true;    //return error
    $return['login'] = 'Niet alle velden zijn ingevuld';
} else {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $wachtwoord = $_POST['wachtwoord'];

    //Check if user exists
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM gebruiker WHERE email = '$email'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);    

    if($num_rows == 0){
        $return['error'] = true;
        $return['login'] = 'Gebruiker bestaat niet';
    } else {
        //Check if password is correct for user
        $sql_2 = "SELECT * FROM gebruiker WHERE email = '$email'  && wachtwoord = '$wachtwoord'";
        $query_2 = mysql_query($sql_2);
        $num_rows_2 = mysql_num_rows($query_2);
        if($num_rows_2 == 0){
            $return['error'] = true;
            $return['login'] = 'Wachtwoord onjuist';
        } else {
            $return['error'] = false;
            $return['login']['email'] = $email;
            $return['login']['wachtwoord'] = $wachtwoord;
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you've riddled the code with typos, you're mixing two entirely seperate mysql libraries:

```
$con=mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbnaam);// or die($db_error1);
          ^---note the presence of an 'i'
```

and in the other scripts:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
               ^---note the LACK of an 'i'
```

mysql and mysqli are **NOT** interchangeable, and connections established in one are utterly useless for the other.

The mysql (**WITHOUT** an i) library is obsolete and deprecated. Stick with mysqli (**WITH** an i) only.

Comment: thanks for your reply, ok changed the $result = mysqli in the other script.

also switched the direction of the connect.php file but but of the solutions won't help.